# Measuring code complexity of a recursive function

Tags: code-complexity

According to my professor, this code is Teta(n^n)

Measuring line by line i cant discover myself why its n^n complexity

this is the code

```
any(v[], n, degree){
   for(i=0; i<degree; i++){
      any(v,n-1,degree)
   }
}
```

i have been making myself.

```
any(v[], n, degree){
   for(i=0 - C; i<degree c(n+1); i++ cn){ 
      any(v,n-1,degree) n(T(n-1))
   }
}
```

It is `2c+2cn+n(T(n-1))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start, it looks like this would actually be infinite since it doesn't break or return at n==0. Assuming that the algorithm does return at n==0 (it would have to in an if statement that is currently missing):

T(n) = degree*T(n-1), where T(0) = 1 and T(1) = degree

This reduces to O(degree^n)

I'm not really sure where the n^n comes from. Unless I did the maths wrong.

Comment: at this point ok. Whats the resolution for T(n-1) on this case?

Answer (score 1):

Your professor is right, that code would run for ever recursively calling itself and n growing negative. if that is not what you want, then you would have to implement a condition to end the recursion, i.e. value of n:

```
any(v[], n, degree){
   if (n > -1) {
       for(i=0;i< degree;i++){
          any(v,n-1,degree)
       }
   }
}
```